# Define a function and name it "numbers_range" that receives arbitrary list of numerical numbers and returns the range of the numbers

Tags: python

Question from my intro to python class that I'm stuck on.

This is what I have tried so far, but I keep getting an error saying:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
# define the function
def numbers_range (*args):
    return max(args) - min(args)

# test the function
numbers = ([20, 10, 5, -1, 10])
numbers_range(numbers)
```

For example, passing these numbers "20, 10, 5, -1, 10" should return the value of 21.

Comment: What do you think `range(args)` is doing? And why are you iterating if you're not using `numbers`?

Comment: What would 'the range of numbers from an arbitrary list of numerical numbers' be?

Comment: You need to remove the `*`, or add another one.

Comment: English is not my native language, but I'd say the question wants `min` and `max` of the list of numbers that have been passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is the range from lowest to highest, you can use `min` and `max` for this.

```py
def number_range(input_list):
    return min(input_list), max(input_list)
```

```
>>> number_range([20, 10, 5, -1, 10])
>>> (-1, 20)
```

If you want the range of all the function's argument, and not of a list passed as argument, you can use [the unpacking operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists), `*`

```py
def number_range_args(*args):
    return min(args), max(args)
```

```
>>> number_range(20, 10, 5, -1, 10)
>>> (-1, 20)
```

Note: it seems your homework is about finding the size of the delta, not just the lower and upper bound. Know that you can turn a negative number into a positive with `abs()`

I'll leave it as an exercize to the reader how to go from the bounds to the size of the range.

Comment: My professor wants us to use "args" instead of "input_list".  For example if I were to pass numbers "20, 10, 5, -1, 10", it should return "21"

Comment: You can expand the array into arguments with the `*` operator. See the edit.